# How do I create a JComboBox loop so the same combobox will appear multiple times?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

Im trying to create a loop to create this JComboBox multiple times on the page. Any idea why this isnt working?

```
        String[] numbers = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
        JComboBox numberbox = new JComboBox(numbers); 
     for(int j = 1; j <= 12; j++){
        numberbox[j].setLocation(103,j*30);
        numberbox[j].setSize(47,26);
        numberbox[j].setSelectedIndex(1);
        numberbox[j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panelForTextFields.add(numberbox[j]);
        numberbox[j].addActionListener(this);
     }
```

I believe it is a working code other than the loop part. When I replace it with this chunk of code it does print a single JComboBox that works as I want.

```
        String[] numbers = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
        JComboBox numberbox = new JComboBox(numbers); 
        numberbox.setLocation(103,30);
        numberbox.setSize(47,26);
        numberbox.setSelectedIndex(1);
        numberbox.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panelForTextFields.add(numberbox);
        numberbox.addActionListener(this);
```

Error im recieving in eclipse is "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to JComboBox"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error im recieving in eclipse is "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to JComboBox"

Yep, the `numberbox` variable is not declared as an array, but you're trying to use it as an array, and so Java (not Eclipse) is correctly telling you that you can't do this. First declare the variable as an array (or perhaps better as an `ArrayList<JComboBox>`), and then create *each* JComboBox inside the for loop. Also, use layout managers and avoid absolute positioning of your components.

i.e.,

```
String[] numbers = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
JPanel myGridLayoutUsingJPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
JComboBox[] combos = new JComboBox[MAX_COMBOS]; // MAX_... is a constant
for (int i = 0; i < combos.length; i++) {
  combos[i] = new JComboBox(numbers);
  combos[i].addActionListener(someActionListener);
  myGridLayoutUsingJPanel.add(combos[i]);
}

// add myGridLayoutUsingJPanel to the GUI...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the same JCombobox in your loop. You need to do new in te loop as well to create and add different JCombbox. Here is the updated code:

```
 String[] numbers = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
 JComboBox numberbox = null;
 for(int j = 1; j <= 12; j++){
    numberbox = new JComboBox(numbers); 
    numberbox.setLocation(103,j*30);
    numberbox.setSize(47,26);
    numberbox.setSelectedIndex(1);
    numberbox.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panelForTextFields.add(numberbox);
    numberbox.addActionListener(this);
 }
```

Comment: You need `numberbox = new ...` instead of just `new`.

Comment: One more thing, you can't do `numberbox[j]`, numberbox isn't an array.